# Error "Cannot determine a valid Java Home" when launching Java Web Start (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, java, environment-variables, java-web-start

I'm using a Windows 10 system.

I need to use a program, which is opened by clicking on a Windows shortcut.
Checking the shortcut's properties, I see the following as destination:

C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\javaws.exe -localfile -J-Djnlp.application.href=http://jws.agenziaentrate.it/jws/dichiarazioni/2019/RPF19.jnlp "C:\Users\Pc\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\cache\6.0\25\33dde299-6b4cf49f"

But when I double click on the shortcut, I get an error dialogue stating: "Cannot determine a valid Java Home"

The same happens if I simply double click on the javaws.exe executable.

I already tried setting the %JAVA_HOME% environment variable to a valid value, and rebooted the system, to no avail.

I may I solve this problem?

Comment: What is your `%JAVA_HOME%` environment variable?

Comment: It's "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144". I have a working JDK installation there.

Comment: Something is fishy with your software application. In my JRE software installation, a path is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_202\bin\javaws.exe`. Your JDK is also installed in the `C:\Program Files\ ` folder. My `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\ ` folder does not contain any files. It contains only a folder. Now, why does your software application attempt to start the `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\javaws.exe` binary executable file? Can you try to understand that?